# Ударение "на закорки"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Как правильно говорить: *на зáкорки* или *на закóрки*?

Answer (score 3):

**На закОрки**. Означает на плечи и  верхнюю часть спины и  произносится с ударением на втором слоге.